# Plot functions with specific orientation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a graph with more than one function. My goal is at the point that function a ends, function b start but with an angle.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = 5
l = 5
vnp1 = 3

h1 = np.arange(0, h+1, 1)

a = (vnp1*1000) * h1  / 1000

l1 = np.arange(0, l+1, 1)

b = (vnp1*1000) ** 2 * l1  / 1000


plt.plot(h1, a)

plt.plot(l1, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like the x-axis of the second function to be modified. Try this:

```
plt.plot(h1, a)
plt.plot(np.arange(h1[-1], h1[-1]+l+1, 1), b)
```

Comment: @akanskha It worked! However, is it possible to make the angle a variable and function b orientation be according to that angle?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in matplotlib. Plus, since your function reflects the orientation change, it is not necessary to have an extra angle variable for plotting purposes.